# How to group rows that have same Group IS as a foreign key?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I just trying  to make a group of students who have the same group ID and calculate the CGPA of only those students who have belong to the same Group.
[Refrence Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utMVB.png)

Here's is the code for Controller

```
public function View_GroupStudent()
{
    $allot_app = AllotmentApps::select(
        "AllotmentApps.grpID",
        "AllotmentApps.sname",
        "AllotmentApps.cgpa"
    )
    ->orderBy('grpID')
    ->get();
   
    return  view('deny', compact('allot_app'));
}
```

Views:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Group Id</th>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Individuals CGPA</th>
    <th>Group CGPA</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  @foreach ($allot_app as $allot_app)
    <td>{{ $allot_app->grpID }}</td> 
    <td>{{ $allot_app->sname }}</td>
    <td>{{ $allot_app->cgpa }}</td>
    <td>{{ $allot_app->sum('cgpa') }}</td>
  </tr>   
  @endforeach
</table>
```

Also help me in creating a proper view for that.

Comment: Your @foreach should be one line higher. Also, I do not understand what you're trying to calculate. Or the formula

Comment: See the Reference image you wil know what Im trying to calculate.

Comment: Im trying to calculate the Individuals Cgpa of students  who have the same Group ID

Comment: Your image is confusing. Write down the formula.

Comment: Group Cgpa= Individual Cgpa of those students who have the same GrpID/3; A=2.5, B=3.78, C=3.9, Group Cgpa= A+B+C/3;

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by your image because the red numbers weren't the averages at all. You should be able to achieve what you're trying to do with the following:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Group Id</th>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Individuals CGPA</th>
    <th>Group CGPA</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach ($allot_app->groupBy('grpID') as $grouped)
    @foreach ($grouped as $allot_app)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $allot_app->grpID }}</td> 
        <td>{{ $allot_app->sname }}</td>
        <td>{{ $allot_app->cgpa }}</td>
        <td>{{ number_format($grouped->avg('cgpa'), 2) }}</td>
      </tr>   
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: This view is not showing even a single record. Please help me in solving this problem